# Asp.net (MVC)Core 2.1 version Jquery Data table plugin issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>
<div class="container">
    <br />
    <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>CustomerID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>               
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#example").DataTable({
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
            "ajax": {
                "url": "https://data.sfgov.org/resource/RowID.json",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columnDefs":
                [{
                    "targets": [0],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false
                }],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "number_of_alarms", "name": "number_of_alarms", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "on_scene_dttm", "name": "on_scene_dttm", "autoWidth": true },
            ]

        });
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to use jquery.dataTables.min.js in my asp.net mvc core 2.1 version.
Though i have included my script lib in correct order i am getting the error saying  "uncaught typeerror $(...).datatable is not a function".

Answer (score 0):

this a typo?
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

should be 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes typo sorry for that but even facing same issue

Comment: yeah I grabbed it, threw it in a running sample and it was having issues.  I think part of it has to do with amount data and city of sf's options you might look at doing odata or even trying constrain the data.  more or less I couldn't get it run either. also keep in mind that running 2 jquery versions could be bad too since by default 3.3.1 is installed in templates for asp.net core 2.1